# Python3 Matplotlib psutil script not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, psutil

So i have an issue. I have two Scripts running one which is a CPU and Time logger of every second to record the CPU usage to a text file. The other is a Script that reads the text file into a graph but the graph is not a uniform axis and does not increase in units and i get the wrong output view.

Script1: logs PSU and time to txt file

```
import psutil import time
print(str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())) + ", " +
      str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)))
f = open("example.txt", "a+")
f.write(str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())) + 
      ", " + str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)) + " \n")
```

Program 2: plots to a graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure() ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open ('example.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000) plt.show()
```

[Script2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvlps.png)

If this can be made into one Script then great but i am trying to learn the basics. I think it is a String issue with writing to txt files but dont know why a string would matter in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the string you need to write in the TXT o CSV file will be generated by (in CSV is much easier to read before):

```
import time
import psutil
import csv

num_measures = 10
with open("cpu_pcnt.csv", mode='w') as file:
    for _ in range(num_measures): 
        str_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        cpu_pcnt = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
        str_data = f"{str_time},{cpu_pcnt}\n"
        file.write(str_data)
```

Then, convert the time in datetime object to the plot and look to cast the pcu percent into float:

```
def animate(i):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    
    with open("cpu_pcnt.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in reader:
            xs.append(datetime.strptime(line[0], "%H:%M:%S"))
            ys.append(float(line[1]))
            
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "animation.py", line 951, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "animation.py", line 1743, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "animation.py", line 1766, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "Plotter.py", line 15, in animate
    reader = csv.reader(file)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined